# C# how to copy templet object data to a new object , but no the address

Tags: c#, oop, object

i basically want to define  a  templet data object , 
and use this templet data object to assign new data objects.
then put different values to  new data objects.

code like:

```
public class sData
{
    public  string name;
    public  int Number;
    public sData(string name,int Number)
    {
        this.poster_path = path;
        this.Number = Number;
    }
}

sData templet= new sData("aaaa","0");

sData realData1 = new sData();
realData1=templet;
realData1.Number=100;
```

but after  `realData1.Number=100;`

i found the  `templet.Number` is changed to `100`

how can i just give the `100` to `realData1` , but no the `templet` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I correct in saying that you'd like to setup some a factory object which will create data objects with pre-defined set of values (i.e. a template)?

The code you have above won't do that.  You have only created one object but you have two different references to it.

Perhaps something like this will do what you need:

```
public class sData
{
    public string name;
    public int Number;
    public sData(string name,int Number)
    {
        this.poster_path = path; //copied from question, this might need updating.
        this.Number = Number;
    }

    sData CreateCopy()
    {
        return new sData(name, number);
    }

}


sData template = new sData("aaaa","0");

sData realData1 = template.CreateCopy();
realData1.Number=100;
```

This still doesn't feel very elegant, perhaps separate classes for the factory and the data object would be more appropriate, but it's hard to say without more context.

Comment: well i know that way,  but the big class is generated by EF and no supposed to edit. so far i just get all the columns copy to each new object....

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the object variable of `templet` to `realData1` and this way you are still referencing the same object in memory:

```
realData1=templet;
```

You can assign the values instead of the object itself:

```
realData1.name = templet.name;
realData1.Number = templet.Number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Class is of reference type and the reference variables of class sData *realData1* and *templet* point to the same memory location in heap, so the value of  *templet* is getting overwritten by the value *realData1*.